# OWASP Dependency check suppress doesn't work

Tags: gitlab-ci, owasp, suppression, owasp-dependency-check

I am trying to use owasp dependency check in gitlab-ci job using latest owasp docker image.
Dependency check works well, but when I tried to add suppress xml file, it doesn't work - it doesn't suppress any vulnerability.

Here is how I am using the dependency check:

```
.owasp_scanning: &owasp_scanning
  stage: security-scanning
  image:
    name: owasp/dependency-check:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  needs: []
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
  - |
    if [ -e "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/suppressions.xml" ]; then
      echo "Suppression file found: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/suppressions.xml"
      cat "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/suppressions.xml"
    else
      echo "Suppression file not found: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/suppressions.xml"
    fi
  script:
    # prints owasp dependency check version
    - /usr/share/dependency-check/bin/dependency-check.sh --version
    # prints full report and create artifact
    - /usr/share/dependency-check/bin/dependency-check.sh --scan "$CI_PROJECT_DIR" \
      -f HTML -o "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/dependency-check-report.html" \
      --project "$CI_PROJECT_NAME" --failOnCVSS 0 \
      --suppression "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/suppressions.xml"
```

In before_script part I can see that the file is on the located right and it containes expected code.
Here is suppressions.xml, which is created from "suppress" button in dependency check report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suppressions xmlns="https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-suppression.1.3.xsd">
   <suppress>
      <notes><![CDATA[
      file name: standing_order_kucmin.jar: guava-28.1-jre.jar
      ]]></notes>
      <packageUrl regex="true">^pkg:maven/com\.google\.guava/guava@.*$</packageUrl>
      <cpe>cpe:/a:google:guava</cpe>
   </suppress>
   <suppress>
      <notes><![CDATA[
      file name: standing_order_kucmin.jar: commons-io-2.5.jar
      ]]></notes>
      <packageUrl regex="true">^pkg:maven/commons\-io/commons\-io@.*$</packageUrl>
      <cve>CVE-2021-29425</cve>
   </suppress>
</suppressions>
```

Can someone see something I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance